# Gnash installation flash player

Tags: software-installation

Gnash is a nice flash player which is outdated and unsupported this year, the package and dependencies still can be downloaded from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnash, can I install them to Focal Fossa, like Amule, can it?

Answer (score 0):

You try to manually install them, but there are no guarantees they'll still work, and if you get dependency errors (because they require library versions that no longer exist) that's the end of it.

If you can get your hands on the source packages and know a few things about compiling you might get a little longer life out of it, but there's almost certainly a reason it's no longer supported.